# Reading zip files stored in GAE Blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I have followed the sample code below to upload a zip file in the blobstore. I am able to upload the zip file in but i have some concerns reading the file.

Sample Code http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Complete_Sample_App

My zip file has 6 CSV files where my system will read the files and import the values in the datastore. However i am aware that there are some restrictions to read the file which must be less than 1MB.

Can anyone suggest how i can go about reading the zip file and process the CSV file? What will happen if my data saved in the blobstore is more than 1MB?

Hope to hear from you. Advance thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Individual API calls to the blobstore API must be less than 1MB, but you can read as much data as you want with multiple calls. See [this blog post](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/08/Using-BlobReader-wildcard-subdomains-and-webapp2) for an example of using BlobReader to read the contents of a zip file from the blobstore; it's written using Python, but BlobReader is available in the Java SDK too, and the same technique applies.